# Different batteries in a parallel circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]
I have come across this question in my physics textbook. Two batteries are connected in parallel to a resistor (see the above image). The first battery generates $U1 = 9V$ of voltage and its internal resistance is $R1 = 0.45\Omega$, while the second battery generates $U2 = 6V$ of voltage and its internal resistance is $0.3\Omega$. Resistance of the resistor is $R3 = 2\Omega$. The task is to find the power of the resistor and both batteries.

Just to clarify, I am not looking for solutions, as they are already provided by the textbook (power of the resistor is $22W$, power of the first battery is $28W$ and power of the second battery is -12W -- assume that the battery is rechargeable). I am struggling to understand these solutions and would like to know how to tackle problems like this. Any explanation or derivation of these results would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: Have you tried using Kirchhoff's laws on the circuit?

Comment: @Steeven This is where I start having troubles. I assume that according to KVL U1 - I1*R1 - U2 + I2*R2 = 0. Is this correct?

Comment: Per Steeven, do KVL. Get two loop equations with  two unknowns (the loop currents) and solve for the currents in each resistor. Then apply $P=I^{2}R$ to each resistor to get the power. Do you know how to apply Kirchoff's voltage law?

Comment: Seeing your inclusion of a circuit, I'm assuming $R_1$ is the 20 ohm resistor. Where are the internal resistances of the batteries?

Comment: @BobD resistance of the first battery is 0.45ohms. resistance of the second battery is 0.3ohms. resistance of the resistor (which I incorrectly labeled as R1 instead of R3) is 2ohms

Comment: @starless_77 Yes but you don't show them in the circuit diagram.

Comment: @BobD Yeah I know. Btw, you said that you would get two loop equations with two unknowns? How?

Comment: Look at  my circuit. Make one loop include V1, its internal resistor, and R1. Choose a direction of loop current I1 (clockwise for example. Doesn't matter as it will come out as either + or -). Then make the second loop include V2, its internal resistor, and R1 and label current I2. Now you have two equations and two unknowns. Be careful about determining the current in R1, because it will be the algebraic sum of the two loop currents as both go through R1.

Comment: The currents and the voltages in a linear circuit are simply the sums of the currents and the voltages that are caused by each of its independent sources.  First, "null out" V2 (i.e., replace it with a straight piece of wire), and calculate the current and voltage at each resistor caused by V1. Then, null out V1 and calculate the currents and voltages that are due to V2. Add them up, and you're done.  NOTE: Don't "null out" the batteries' "internal resistances," R1 and R2. Only null out the voltage sources.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Awesome. Thank you so much man.

Comment: @starless_77 Solomon is showing you how to solve the problem using superposition. That's fine and its what those who are familiar with all the approaches  and can see the easiest would do. But I sense you are relatively new at these concepts. In my opinion, you should first be familiar on using Kirchoff's laws. I suggest you also try to solve using loop equations so that you become familiar with the tool. Not all problems are as easy as this one.

Comment: @BobD I'm sorry but I didn't really understand your advice. Can you maybe write out those equations so I can see what I'm dealing with?

Comment: @starless_77 OK, I'll put together a short tutorial for you.

Comment: @BobD OK I think I understand what you meant. I1*R1 + R3*I3 = U1,   I2*R2 + R3*I3 = U2   and I1 + I2 = I3 and the solution is correct

Comment: @starless_77 Not sure what you did. It wasn't loop analysis because there should only be 2 loop currents. You have three currents.  Something is redundant. Did you actually solve the equations and get the book answers?

Comment: @starless_77 I looked at your equations and they don’t solve the problem, at least I couldn't solve it that way.  I’m not sure what you did because you didn’t provide a circuit diagram showing where you put I1, I2  and I3.  So, I will give you (coming soon) the tutorial on how to set up the problem using Kirchoff’s Voltage Law (KVL). Bob

Comment: @starless_77 See the ADDENDUM and revision to my answer to hopefully help you understand how to apply KVL. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the internal resistances of the batteries in the proper locations in the circuit diagram before you can apply KVL.

**ADDENDUM:**

Per your request, The following are the steps typically taken in applying Kirchhoff’s Voltage Law (KVL). See my revised circuit diagram below that demonstrates the application of the steps to your circuit.

1. ***Assign loop currents***. The loops can be arbitrarily selected along with the direction of the loop currents. I chose the ones shown below.
2. ***Show the polarities of the voltages across each circuit element due to the loop currents.*** By convention current is the flow of positive charge. Show the polarity of the resistors as (+) to (–) in the direction of current flow.
3. ***Apply KVL to each loop***. Go around each loop in the direction of the loop current and algebraically add the voltages across each resistor and voltage source.  Set the sum equal to zero. When going from (+) to (-) across any element the voltage is negative (voltage drop).  When going from (-) to (+) the voltage is positive (voltage rise).

**CAUTION**: Don’t only to count the voltage drop/rise in a resistor due the loop current under consideration, but also include any drop/rise due to another loop current if that current also goes through the resistor.  This is the case for $R_3$ in my diagram because both loop currents go through that resistor. I think you may have neglected this when you developed your equations.

**Loop 1:**
$+9-(0.45)I_{1}-(2)I_{1}-(2)I_{2}=0$

**Loop 2:**
$+6-(0.3)I{2}-(2)I_{2}-(2)I_{1}=0$

Solve the simultaneous equations to obtain $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$.  Then compute power in $R3$ and “power of the batteries”.

The following are my results:

$I_{1}=5.32A$

$I_{2}=-2.02A$

Which means the actual loop current in loop 2 is opposite that assumed. The current in R3 is

$I_{R3}=5.32-2.20=3.03A$

The power dissipated in R3 is (per the book solution)

$P_{R3}=(3.03^{2})(2)≈22w$

The power that charges the 6 volt battery and becomes stored energy in the battery is

$P_{V2}=(2)(6)=12 w$

The negative sign given in the book simply means that power is delivered to rather than extracted from the battery cells. Note, however that there is also power dissipated as heat in the 6 volt battery's internal resistance and is

$P_{R2}=(2^{2})(.3)=1.2w$

Battery 1 (9 v):

The power generated internal to the 9 volt battery is

$(9)(5.32)≈48w$

Part of that power is dissipated in its internal resistance and is

$(5.32^{2})(0.45)≈12.7w$.

The power that this battery actually delivers to the rest of the circuit connected to terminals A and B is

$48-12.7=35.3w$

None of these match what you said the book solution was, namely 28 watts. So I’m not sure how they got 28 watts. But here is a reality check on my results. We know that the total power dissipated in all the resistors plus that being stored in battery 2 should equal the power developed within battery 1, which was 48 watts.

**POWER DISSIPATED/STORED:**

$P_{R1}=(5.32^2)(0.45)=12.7w$

$P_{R3}=(3.3^{2})(2)=22w$

$P_{R2}=(2^{2})(0.3)=1.2w$

$P_{battery 2}= (2)(6)=12 w$

Total = 48 watts

One final point. You could also solve this problem by superposition as suggested by @Solomon Slow, and sometimes it can be done quicker that way. But I believe one really needs to learn and apply Kirchhoff’s laws first before using other techniques.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is great, thank you so much. I ended up getting the same results, but your explanation helped me understand the situation better.

Comment: You are welcome.